# Creating Pairs for Training a Siamese Network for Speaker Verification Text Dependent

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to build a siamese network for speaker verification using `python`. This network consists of 2 identical Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) to learn a similarity function which can distinguish whether 2 input voice belong to the same person or not.

#### Data

I have 10 person recording their voice in `.wav` saying digits of 9 number in Bahasa `(satu, dua, tiga, empat, lima, enam, tujuh, delapan, sembilan)` each person records 5 times for each number, so each person have 45 recordings `(9 x 5)`. I used MFCC to get features vector and got vector shape `(450, 250, 13)` -- (rows, number_frames, number_cepstral) and now I want to make a pair of my data

I have seen these link 
- https://www.kaggle.com/arpandhatt/siamese-neural-networks 
- https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/

But I cannot understand what kind of methods which being used to create the pairs. Given my data, how can I create good pairs to train the siamese network?

**Notes**: I want to build speaker verification text dependent which means one recording saying `'satu'` will be compared to another recording saying `'satu'` too.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the end-to-end speaker verification systems, which are essentially siamese networks for speaker verification.

[L. Wan, et al., "Generalized end-to-end loss for speaker verification," in Proc. ICASSP, 2018.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.10467)

I think the literature above may give you intuition on your problem.